# 2 Possible Radii for Circular Motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I was solving a task dealing with electricity/magnetism, in which a charged, dimensionless particle was simultaneously affected by a uniform magnetic field and the electric field emitted by a fixed/stationary point charge, such that both of the resulting forces were centripetal and the particle was stated to be performing a uniform circular motion. (The two charged particles are of opposite signs, and the magnetic field is perpendicular to the plane of the circular motion.)

[image: Illustration.]

The task was to calculate the radius. My attempt to do so resulted in an expression that implied two possible solutions for it. I checked, both solutions are valid in the sense that the radius is positive. I was confused because I'm not sure exactly how it works that, given specific, concrete details of the forces acting upon a particle, there'd be *two* possible radii, meaning two totally different routes the particle "might" take. I looked at the official solution and it simply said, "There are two possible radii."

The only possible explanation I could come up with is that the particle isn't actually necessarily performing circular motion, which is why things get slightly wonky (for instance, that perhaps the force by the fixed charge is only centripetal at first, but doesn't afterwards stay in the center of the circular path; and then I'd assume it truly is circular motion only if both solutions for radii are identical, meaning there's only one possible radius, so the net centripetal force is pulling towards a specific center).

Would really appreciate an explanation of what exactly is the physical meaning of this, since I'm very far from being sure about my own reasoning expressed above.

(In the case my specific calculations are required, then: $R$ is the radius, $F{\scriptsize el}$ is the electric force by the point charge, F${\scriptsize b}$ is the magnetic force, $e$ is the absolute value of the charge of each of the two charged particles, $v$ is the magnitude of the initial velocity vector, $b$ is the magnitude of the magnetic field, $k$ is the Coulomb constant.

$
F{\scriptsize el} = k\frac{e^2}{R^2}\\
F{\scriptsize b} = evb\cdot\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) = evb\\
\sum F {\scriptsize centripetal} = F{\scriptsize el} + F{\scriptsize b} = evb + k\frac{e^2}{R^2} = m \cdot a = m \frac{V^2}{R}\\
\Rightarrow (evb) \cdot R^2 - (mv^2) \cdot R + (ke^2) = 0
$

And the two solutions to this quadratic equation are the radii in question.)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You can get multiple solutions in equations all the time. For example, for an orbiting planet there are _infinitely_ many possible circular orbit radii, since any radius works.

Comment: For example, the equation $x^2 = 9$ has two solutions, $3$ and $-3$. That doesn't mean that the solution "isn't actually necessarily $3$ or $-3$", or "isn't truly $3$ or $-3$ unless $3$ and $-3$ are identical". It just means that if $x^2 = 9$, then there are two possible values for $x$.

Comment: @knzhou It's not the algebra that confuses me but the physics. That is, I struggle with picturing the physical meaning of there being two solutions in this case. If the object is travelling in a circular path in uniform circular motion, then doesn't it mean its route is in the form of a specific circle? And if so then how can a specific circle have multiple possible radii?

Comment: No, you've only showed that the particle _can_ travel in circles of two different radii. What it _actually_ does depends on things like its initial position and velocity. If you give it one particular set of initial positions and velocities, it might move in the smaller circle. If you give it another, it might move in the larger circle. If you give it yet another, it might not move in a circle at all.

Comment: Penny just dropped, I believe. The missing piece of information is its starting position relative to the fixed charge, and there could be two possible starting positions (each of them being the radius in their respective scenarios) that would cause the particle to travel in a circular motion. Awesome!

Comment: Thanks a lot, knzhou! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I said you had a cannon with a fixed charge in it and you wanted to know the angle required to hit a specific target, would you be surprised to find it's a quadratic with two solutions?  Near 45 degrees, the ammo overshoots the target.  Near 90 and 0 degrees, the ammo does not reach it.  But at two points between, the target is reached.

A similar process is happening here.  At small values of R the charge dominates.  At high values of R, the magnetic field force dominates.  Both have more force than is necessary to keep the moving particle in a circular orbit.

Between the two extremes, the $mv^2$ term is large enough that the inertia of the moving particle can't be overcome and the motion takes it away from the center.

But there will be two boundaries between these three regions where an unstable equilibrium exists and the forces are exactly equal to the requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Really good explanation. You & knzhou made things very clear for me.